# Unable to stop, remove war file and start tomcat using SSH

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I am trying to develop a GitLab pipeline to deploy a war file into EC2 tomcat.
I am moving the war file successfully to EC2 to the folder home/ec2-user.
From there I am trying to copy the war file to tomcat8/webapps folder which is before home (Main folder level).

I am using the following code but it is throwing error like "No Such File or Directory" when trying to shutdown or startup the server.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER "sudo echo '1stline'"
ssh ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER "sudo sh /tomcat8/bin/shutdown.sh"
ssh ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER "sudo echo '2ndline'"
ssh ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER "sudo rm -rf /tomcat8/webapps/gitlabec2pipeline.war"
ssh ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER "sudo echo '3rdline'"
ssh ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER "sudo cp /home/ec2-user/gitlabec2pipeline.war /tomcat8/webapps/gitlabec2pipeline.war"
ssh ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER "sudo echo '4thline'"
ssh ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER "sudo sh /tomcat8/bin/startup.sh"
```

The following is the error. (If I run the above steps manually in EC2 instance they are working fine).

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ echo -e "$EC2_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ scp target/*.war ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER:/home/ec2-user/gitlabec2pipeline.war
Warning: Permanently added '3.216.147.37' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
$ bash .gitlab-deploy-ec2.sh
1stline
: No such file or directory
2ndline
3rdline
4thline
: No such file or directory
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Can anyone help me with what mistake I am doing here?
Thank you.

Comment: **You have carriage-returns** in your script file, probably due to editting or creating on Windows, or capturing from something like `script` or `ssh -t`. Examine with `cat -v` or `od -c` or similar, and fix with `dos2unix` or similar.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're using the correct path on the server? Can you run `find`, `tree`, or `ls -R` on the `/tomcat8` directory or otherwise confirm the scripts are where you expect them to be and are readable/executable by the ec2-user user?

Comment: @sytech, I am using the correct paths as I am able to execute them manually. The problem is with the carriage-returns as I developed the shell scripts in windows and trying to execute it in linux. Using dos2unit, I fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, Thank you. The problem is with the carriage-returns. I fixed it using dos2unix and the scripts are working fine. Thank you very much.